# Watch isolatebindings as collection in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, watch

I'm wondering if there is a way to watch all $$isolateBindings in my directive ?

```
$scope.$watch('$$isolateBindings', function() {
   console.log('watch me plse'); 
});
```

Now I do it like this:

```
var isolateBindings = []

angular.forEach($scope.$$isolateBindings, function(item) {
    isolateBindings.push(item.attrName)
});



var watchIsValid = $scope.$watchGroup(isolateBindings, function() {
   console.log('do somthing'); 
});
```

Comment: what is the purpose of this?  most `$$` prefixed objects, including `$$isolateBindings`, are meant for internal use only.  are you trying to modify the way that the core of angular functions in some way?  This is definitely an XY question.

Comment: My purpose is to do something if input filed is changed.

Comment: Why wouldn't you watch the model value in that case? Or use ng-change?  This still seems like a very unorthodox approach, and it's not clear why you are trying to approach your issue this way.

Comment: The whole point of an isolate scope is that the properties of it are, well, *isolated*. Using an isolate scope and then trying to break your way into that scope from the outside is a major code smell.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it has to be

```
var isolateBindings = Object.keys(scope.$$isolateBindings || {});
var watchIsValid = $scope.$watchGroup(isolateBindings, function() {
   console.log('do somthing'); 
});
```

These are scope properties which are watched, not attributes.

It is unlikely that there is another straightforward way to do this. The reasons for that may be arguable, but this approach is good enough to not look any further.